# Terminal equivalent command for Directory Utility View specific user OD data

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, active-directory, open-directory

I wonder if there's any equivalent terminal command that can output the same data displayed when the I search for the domain user Under Users in the OD node (`/Active Directory/MYCOMP/...`)

the data is a dictionary with fields like AltSecurityIdentities, dsAttrTypeNative:.. , and more.

I'm looking for macOS(10.12+) native, command line tool, that can extract an input user AD details that contains fields like `AuthenticationAuthority` and `AltSecurityIdentities` quite similar to Diretory Utility Gui based application (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app`).

Is it possible to script user lookups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that ships with macOS to do LDAP lookups works with many Active Directory servers.

```
dscl /LDAPv3/ldap.company.com -list /Users UniqueID
```

The above command will list out directory users. If you bind your Mac to AD you can get lots more integrations, but it’s not needed to just read the directory. I tries power shell in the past, but ran into errors installing the Active Directory modules but that might also be a promising tool if that fits your definition of “native”

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos